# getTrackingPopUpUrlByOrderId not working

Tags: magento-1.7, shipment-tracking

I have this code.

```
<a href="#" id="linkId" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('shipping')->getTrackingPopUpUrlByOrderId(100000019) ?>','trackshipment','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track this shipment') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track this shipment') ?></a>
```

It is supposed to open a popup with tracking details. But its not working. Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Please note `100000019` is my order id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for `getTrackingPopUpUrlByOrderId` must be the real order id (not the increment) or the `$order` object itself. Try this instead:

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000019)?>
<a href="#" id="linkId" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('shipping')->getTrackingPopUpUrlByOrderId($order) ?>','trackshipment','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track this shipment') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track this shipment') ?></a>
```